# How to save this value in List python [BeautifulSoup]?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

[image: I want this marked values to get saved in a list.]

Full code: [hastebin link](https://hastebin.com/etutagosug.makefile)

```
name = []
operator = []
state = []
email = []

for heading in soup.findAll(['h4']):
    info = heading.find('font', attrs={'color':'#E03616'})
    print(info.text.strip())
```

So what I want is::

I want values like "Light Stark" to be saved in name list, Jio in operator list, Madhya Pradesh in state list, and lightstark@gmail.com in email list, I'm searching it's solution since hours but didn't found any, please help me..  Like how to do this ?? is there any method like font tag with index [0] get saved in name, like this how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

name = []
operator = []
state = []
email = []
dummy = []

URL = 'https://lightstark24.github.io/weird-tests/w1.html'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for heading in soup.findAll(['h4']):
    info = heading.find('font', attrs={'color':'#E03616'})
    print(info.text.strip())
    dummy.append(info.text.strip())

name.append(dummy[0])
operator.append(dummy[1])
state.append(dummy[2])
email.append(dummy[3])

print(name)
print(operator)
print(state)
print(email)
```

Comment: thank you so much brother <3 this literally solved all my query... thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

im not seeing the specific code but i think you´re scraping the whole header at once, i might get deeper into the header and **scrape** the 4 different things by their own and then i´ll append them to the given lists :)

Comment: here is the page url i m using for demo purpose of scraping: 
    https://lightstark24.github.io/weird-tests/w1.html     please can you tell how or share any article link stating how to do the method you mentioned ..

Comment: Mm my question is the following, are you effectively webscraping those elements? Do you already have them stored on a given list? if you have so you can use a for loop to append each item you want to the lists for example. I´ll leave you a tutorial that was very useful for me when i learnt to webscrap. https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/

Comment: If you don´t have them it might be useful to scrap each item to the same list and then separate things with a for loop that will do that task you´re seeking to do so.